# iOS app not working offline after installing parse notifications - xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, notifications, wifi

does anyone have a solution for this? after following the tutorial on parse for notifications on iOS the app does not launch if there is no internet connection both on simulator and actual device.. please advise for any solution. the source for this is on https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications . the debugger outcome:

```
2012-08-21 19:20:22.415 app[555:c07] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 
"The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0xc50d470 
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/create, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/create, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet 
connection appears to be offline., NSUnderlyingError=0xc509070 "The Internet connection 
appears to be offline."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.0.64)

2012-08-21 19:20:22.415 pyxida3[555:c07] Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.517845 seconds.
```

Comment: This is clear as mud.  Can you please explain what you are trying to do?  Do you actually mean "push notifications"?

Comment: i followed the tutorial on parse ios push notifications and succeeded. but the app does not launch nor on the simulator or the actual device if is not connected on the network (wifi). when launching the app it stucks on the splash screen (default.png) and does not enter into the main controller (in my case tabbar app).

Comment: Please add some code.  Also be aware that Push Notifications do not work in the simulator.

Comment: @ElJay the the code is on the website i just posted.. thank you

Comment: I think what ElJay is trying to say: don't make us hunt for it, and debug your code for you. What did you try? How far did you get?

Comment: i know and sorry if i made you believe so.. the problem is that i do not know how to proceed.. the only outcome i get is from the debugger which i just posted. the tutorial is a long one and honestly i do not know where the problem is to try and solve it thats why i posted the source..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone having the same problem just save your objects in background.
in the appDelegate:

```
[testObject saveInBackground];
```